# Benchmarking code with a StopWatch or similar

Tags: go, benchmarking

I'm trying to use Go package "time" to benchmark a function in my program. Been searching around, and people seem to use time.NanoSeconds() - but I think this function is no longer in the time package?

What I need is an easy way to start and stop a timer, and print out the value.

Comment: I believe that function is now equivalent to `time.Now().UnixNano()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the existing functionality of the [testing](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package inside your *_test.go:

```
func BenchmarkMyFunc(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        myBecnhmarkedFunction()
    }
}
```

and invoke `go test -bench RE` (RE is a regexp to select the benches, like `B` as it means `*B*`) typically inside the package/tool directory

Or explicitly from any place in your code - use the [Benchmark](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just before i read your reply I found an easy example of how to use Go's time package, which was pretty much enough for me. I will look at the benchmarking function as well.

`t0 := time.Now() expensiveCall() t1 := time.Now() fmt.Printf("The call took %v to run.\n", t1.Sub(t0))`

Comment: That approach is OK/good/precise enough only for `expensiveCall()` executing long enough, like in orders of magnitude times longer than the machine time resolution is. The testing package can handle nanoseconds accurate timings by adaptively changing the b.N parameter.

Comment: @shaz You could also use time.Since: t0 := time.Now(); expensiveCall(); println("Time: ", time.Since(t0))